# Is there any classpath length limitation in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am using a third-party java software which is based on install4j to be executed as a Windows service. The classpath in the .vmoptions file is quite big (almost 8k characters). When I am adding new jars to this classpath, I come up with some `ClassNotFoundException`, so it seems the newly added jars are not loaded by the JVM.

Is there any limitation on the length of the classpath in the .vmoptions file used by install4j?

Comment: Try running the executable from the command line with the argument `/create-i4j-log` and check the log file. It will tell you what it reads from the .vmoptions file and what it actually passes to the VM as the class path.

Comment: Hello Ingo. Thanks for the argument. It worked and displayed a list of the jars, and I could see that my new jars where correctly added in the classpath by install4j. It finaly turned out that the TSA that was used for signing the jars is no more available, so the TSA chain could not be verified, and the jars were not loaded. Anyway, thanks for your help.